# Default/System Android theme for application

Tags: android, android-theme

I am developing a really light-weight application which does not actually need a dedicated theme, so I removed `android:theme` attribute of the `<application>` tag in *AndroidManifest.xml*. That seems to work except that the application got dark theme. Is there a way to switch to the light one?

To clarify, I would like the application to have default theme that depends on the platform the application is running on, i.e. it is "Holo" for 4, "Material" for 5, and etc. And it is working now that way, but the theme variant is always dark, whilst I need the light one. I set the "minimum API" property to 14, but I am thinking about 11 as well.

Comment: Add back your dedicated theme, with two versions: one in `res/values/` that inherits from `Theme.Holo.Light` and one in `res/values-v21/` that inherits from `Theme.Material.Light`.

Comment: That's pretty reasonable, but what's about future API versions? Will my app stick to "Material" theme even if that theme isn't default on next major Android versions?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing that you can do about this, other than to update your app at that point in time.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!